# Show, and count the first invoice for account for a period

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

For a sales report (made in SQL on Advantage-Database-Server [ADS]) I need to see where the 1st date a account received an invoice. So far not very difficult, I can use the `MIN()` statement for this. But the report needs to show a count of the number of sorted for a specific period.

The tabel `INVOICE` looks something like this, the (*) is only to show the expected result :

```
ACCOUNT   INVOICE_DATE
314       01/01/2014     (*)
314       02/08/2016
314       08/10/2015
208       16/11/2016
208       04/01/2015
208       12/12/2013     (*)
467       01/02/2013     (*)
467       02/02/2013
467       03/10/2015
```

The result has to look something like:

```
2013  2014  2015  2016
 2     1     0     0
```

I have used some code, but until now no restult.
This is my (not working) code:

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT ACCOUNT) as value, MIN(INVOICE_DATE) as period 
from INVOICE  
where [period] 
group by MIN(INVOICE_DATE), ACCOUNT 
order by [periodtype]
```

Comment: Skip the GROUP BY. Use case expressions to do conditional counting, one per year.

Comment: @Coen Does advantage database server can use same functionality as T-SQL? if so, i have solution for you

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I do not know if the Advance Database Server SQL language is the same as T-SQL. I removed the 'GROUP' BY but this also does not gives expected result.